# Remove www. from domains in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Ive got a list of urls in column A, some of them have `www.` some dont, (none of them have `http://` in this example)

What im trying to do is strip the `www.` do ive got a list of domains that i can order alphabeticly. I was looking at using `=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-4)` but not all the domains have `www.` Any idea how you would be able to do this using a formula, rather than VBA so that it can run in both excel and Google Drive ?

---

**EDIT**

Ive now updated the example spreadsheet with Alex Szabó's answer - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x-zjaIh7xpGeyWPbYLAn5RyNjbrDWFQdI_U5WmS3fys/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check for the "www" in the beginning, and if it's there, then strip it by using all letters from the address, except the first 4.

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,4)="www.", RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-4), A2)
```

Comment: You need to include a . in the test for domains like wwwaza.com.

Answer (score 1):

Use an if condition to check for www. as the first 4 characters, and only take the right - 4 it it is...

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="www.",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-4),A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous contribution, in a google spreadsheet another option would be

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A5, "^www.(.+)$"),A2:A5))
```

This formula references all data in col A and will create an output in one column (no need to drag down).

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be really easy to fix with a basic find and replace as follows:

Find: www.
Leave Replace blank.

Comment: +1 for simplicity, i guess the only issue with it is that if a url is `www.sometimeswww.com` it would pick up both the `www.`s

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the substitute function, if the string doesnt have www. it still returns the original string by default

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"www.","")
```